# Comparator Declaration Syntax

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am implementing a priority queue and comparator interface in Java using the following code and using Java 8 as advised below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class Student {
    private int token;
    private String name;
    private double cgpa;

    public Student(int id, String name, double cgpa) {
        super();
        this.token = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;}

    public int getToken() {
        return token;}

    public String getName() {
        return name;}

    public double getCgpa() {
        return cgpa;}
}

class Priorities {
    public List < Student > getStudents(List <String> events) {
        PriorityQueue < Student > student_queue = new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa).reversed().thenComparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getToken));
        List <Student> students = new ArrayList <Student> ();
        for (String e: events) {
            Scanner in =new Scanner(e);
            String event = in.next();
            if (event.equals("ENTER")) {
                String name = in.next();
                float cgpa = in.nextFloat();
                int token = in.nextInt();

                Student student = new Student(token, name, cgpa);
                student_queue.add(student);
            } else if (event.equals("SERVED")) {
                Student first = student_queue.poll();
            } in .close();
        }
        Student first = student_queue.poll();
        if (first == null) {
            return students;
        } else {
            while (first != null) {

                students.add(first);
                first = student_queue.poll();

            }
            return students;
        }

    }
}



public class Solution {
    private final static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final static Priorities priorities = new Priorities();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalEvents = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());    
        List<String> events = new ArrayList<>();

        while (totalEvents-- != 0) {
            String event = scan.nextLine();
            events.add(event);
        }

        List<Student> students = priorities.getStudents(events);

        if (students.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("EMPTY");
        } else {
            for (Student st: students) {
                System.out.println(st.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors but have been unable to resolve the problem.

Solution.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        PriorityQueue < Student > student_queue = new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa).reversed().thenComparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getToken));
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable Comparator
  location: class Priorities
Solution.java:30: error: invalid method reference
        PriorityQueue < Student > student_queue = new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa).reversed().thenComparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getToken));
                                                                                         ^
  non-static method getCgpa() cannot be referenced from a static context
Solution.java:30: error: invalid method reference
        PriorityQueue < Student > student_queue = new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa).reversed().thenComparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getToken));
                                                                                                                                    ^
  non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context
Solution.java:30: error: invalid method reference
        PriorityQueue < Student > student_queue = new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa).reversed().thenComparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getToken));
                                                                                                                                                                    ^
  non-static method getToken() cannot be referenced from a static context
Note: Solution.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors

Comment: share the Student Class

Comment: Please surround your code snippets with triple backticks ``` so they are formatted correctly.

Comment: I have re-formatted and shared the Student class...thank you

Comment: Please share the complete code.

Comment: I have shown the entire code

Comment: Nothing wrong with your PriorityQueue definition. Share the exact steps and full stack trace of the issue to simulate. What input you are giving etc.

Comment: Are you compiling this with an ancient javac that does not understand generics (and the `<Type>` syntax) ?

Comment: I'm still getting errors - I'm using the in-browser compiler from HackerRank

Comment: Hi user207421...can you show me where the ) should go - I am aware that is what the error message says but for some reason am missing/blanking on where the location is for this. The in-browser compile should be able to understand generics as there is a section for compiling generics in the lesson

Comment: Maybe it has trouble with the lambda syntax? `Student::getCgpa`  Do you have to choose "Java8" instead of "Java" for the language? It is listed as a separate environment on https://www.hackerrank.com/environment/languages

Comment: The code above is compiling and working. The only thing I have changed is `public static` for `Student` and `Priorities` classes. It's working fine with both java 8 and 11.

Comment: Hi Thilo - you are correct about the lambda syntax. This was implemented in Java 8 and I was running this using Java 7 theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Java" on Hackerrank means Java 7.

You need to choose "Java 8" to get support for the `Student::getCpa` syntax.

https://www.hackerrank.com/environment/languages

Also note that the current (long-term-supported) Java version is Java 11. So be careful when using newer constructs or API that may not be available on Java 8 either.

Comment: Hi - I tried doing that but this doesn't seem to have solved the error as I am still getting errors.

Comment: If that's the case, you are probably creating some kind of chaos, as the code is working fine.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? I am getting slightly different errors now but will debug this separately rather than repost or edit my question

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can find is you forgot the `import` for `PriorityQueue`.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
```

Other than that, cut-and-paste into my IDE compiles fine.